# Visual Studio Code, integrated terminal "text" configuration

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I want to edit the text of bash in integrated terminal on VSC

I am working on Mac and i change the terminal text of mac going to terminal -> preferences and add this `export PS1="\u:\w$ "` to shell startup command.. where i can past this and use it also on VSC ?

Comment: Have you looked at the settings file?  Maybe something there will help.  Go to code/preferences/settings.  You may want to search for 'terminal.integrated'. There any many (>40)  variables set.

Comment: I already search SVC settings but nothing